# Get one beyond timestamp cutoff in Linq 2 SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a "large" (hundreds of thousands of rows) table (call it dataPoints).  Another table of "events" which has a one-to-many relationship to the datapoints.  The events table has a TimeStamp column of type `DateTimeOffset`.  I want to query all the datapoints in a certain time range, with one important caveat: I need to interpolate to an input cutoff time.

For example:  Let's say I have events at randomly distributed times in the past (-1 hr, -5 hr, -8 hr, -11 hr and -13 hr).  Each of these events created some dataPoints and I want to query all the datapoints in the last 12 hours.  I would need to get the datapoints associated with ALL these points (including the -13 hr point).  The reason for this is because I need data at the cutoff time (-12 hours), therefore I need both the -11 hr point AND the -13 hr point so I can interpolate to -12 hr.  I can't just simply say `where dataPoint.Event.Time > currentTime - 12`, I need to get one more point beyond that.

Is there any way to express this in LINQ to SQL?  I've only come up with 2 ideas:

1) use some heuristic (multiple the cutoff by 2) to make sure I have enough points.  This is not robust and can be wasteful.

2) Query all the events first, sort them, determine which event is the last one I want by just rolling over manually, then query all the datapoints with a timestamp less that that calculated event.  This one requires a lot of code and is also wasteful.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

1. Query all events up to including the cutoff datetime
2. Query the first event earlier than the last event pulled in step 1

If there is an index on the datetime column both will execute quickly. The only problem is an additional round-trip.

This is similar to your idea 2 but you only need to query at most one event in step 2. I don't think this requires a lot of code.

Query 2 goes like this:

```
(from e in db.Events
where e.DateTime < lastDateTime
order by e.DateTime
select e).Take(1)
```

This causes an index seek returning one row. Very efficient.

Comment: What about using First() instead of Take(1)?

Comment: I'm 90% sure this would also translate to a top 1 in SQL. Need to test. Also use FirstOrDefault as there might not be an event.